# running PHP code through XSS

Tags: xss

i'm wondering if we could find an XSS on a site then i can run my PHP code by for example embedding the source in the page or something or using eval in javascript ? any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

no, that would be a remote code execution or remote file inclusion, not a xss.

Comment: Thanks a lot, So is there a way that i can harm the server ? if for example the XSS affect my profile page only which no one can see it .

Comment: filter it anyways. even if it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: how are you doing this anyways? why does the XSS happen? is it a variable in a URL? are you using pdo?

Comment: so i have found the xss on my profile page, and im wondering of anything could potentially lead to execute malicious code on the server .